# How can I tell NSOpenPanel to respect the ⌘A (select all items) key binding?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macvim

[MacVim](https://macvim.org/) is a macOS application with a file open dialog that calls [NSOpenPanel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsopenpanel) with a simple view to show hidden files (see [MMAppController.m's fileOpen method](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/blob/master/src/MacVim/MMAppController.m) and [Miscellaneous.m's showHiddenFilesView method](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/blob/master/src/MacVim/Miscellaneous.m)).

When I open files with MacVim, I can use ⌘A to select all files. But I don't see what it's doing that's any different than what I do below, which does *not* allow me to use ⌘A to select all files.

```
NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[panel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
[panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
if ([panel runModal] == NSModalResponseOK) {
    for ( NSURL* URL in [panel URLs] ) {
        NSLog( @"%@", [URL path] );
    }
} else {
    NSLog( @"ok button not pressed");
}
```

The docs for `NSOpenPanel` and [NSSavePanel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssavepanel), which `NSOpenPanel` inherits don't make any mention of key bindings or other booleans that I might set. The only thing that I saw that might be useful is a custom view but MacVim doesn't appear to be doing anything with `NSView` that relates.

Below is the entire MCV example and how it's compiled. I suspect there's something wrong with the example since I have to click the graphics rectangle first before I can get the open panel to behave. But I don't think that's having an effect on the key bindings.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

void openDialog () {
    @try {
        NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
        [panel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
        [panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
        [panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
        if ([panel runModal] == NSModalResponseOK) {
            for ( NSURL* URL in [panel URLs] ) {
                NSLog( @"%@", [URL path] );
            }
        } else {
            NSLog( @"ok button not pressed");
        }
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [exception callStackSymbols]);
    }
}

void setup () {
    NSWindow *myWindow;
    NSRect    graphicsRect = NSMakeRect(100.0, 350.0, 400.0, 400.0);

    myWindow = [ [NSWindow alloc]
               initWithContentRect: graphicsRect
                         styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskTitled
                                  |NSWindowStyleMaskClosable
                                  |NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable
                           backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                             defer:NO ];

    [myWindow setTitle:@"Open File App"];
    [myWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];
    openDialog();
}

int main (  ) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSApp = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    setup();
    [NSApp run];
    [NSApp release];
    [pool release];
    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

gcc -o $@ -framework Cocoa -isysroot $(SDK) -fobjc-exceptions -std=c99 ofdtest.m
```

EDIT 1

My macOS version is Sonoma 14.2.1.
My Xcode version is 15.2 (15C500b).
I'm using SDK /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk

I'm running the built MCV in iTerm2 but I don't think that matters.

Comment: I tried your code and Command-A selects all files and folders. Is there a "Select All" menu item with key equivalent Command-A?

Comment: ⌘A doesn't work for me either, just like OP.

Comment: @Willeke When the MCV example runs, there is no Apple menu for which to control. There are many questions to ask regarding your inability to repro the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried the first piece of code and I assumed the open panel was used in an app, like MacVim.

Comment: @Willeke It's still useful to know if it works in a more complete app. I plan to add it to a java swing app to replace the crappy choices for file open dialogs. Before I do that, I was thinking it would be good to know if I could make NSOpenPanel behave better than the current choices. Sounds like I should proceed and hope for the best.

Comment: I imagine NSOpenPanel implements the selectAll: responder method.  But something else has to translate a Command-A keystroke into sending the selectAll: method to the first responder.

Comment: @CarlLindberg Seems reasonable that NSOpenPanel should have its own listener that does that and wholly unreasonable for every app that every developer writes be responsible for it.

Comment: No, NSMenu[Item] normally handles that.  You are free to change the target of any menu item.  You can change Command-A to not invoke selectAll: if you really want just by editing it, or add new menu items (or change key bindings) to call other responder methods you define for your app.  Most people would drop the standard Edit menu into their app and get the functionality that way.

Comment: `NSOpenPanel` is designed to be used in an app and doesn't support Select All. `selectAll:` is implemented by `NSBrowser`, `NSOutlineView` and `NSCollectionView`. Try Command-Z, X, C and V in the search field.

Comment: @Willeke MacVim uses NSOpenPanel. When it raises the open panel, you can select all items in the view. I see nothing in its source that coaxes NSOpenPanel to be fully featured.

Comment: MacVim has a Select All menu item with key equivalent Command-A and action `selectAll:`. It is possible to make Command-A work without a menu item but I don't know if it will work (in the future) outside the usual runloop of `NSApplication`. I'm surprised the open panel works at all.

Comment: NSOpenPanel would use NSBrowser internally, I would think, to show the list of files.  But something needs to call [NSApplication.sharedApplication sendEvent:@selector(selectAll:) to:nil from:<sender>] when Command-A is pressed (sending to nil should start at the first responder, and eventually find the NSBrowser implementation).  Either that or a custom event listener, or set up an NSMenu and get it installed somehow.  Or subclass NSOpenPanel and override sendEvent: to look for them.

Comment: @CarlLindberg Sounds like there's a design conflict in my head. In my head, I would want NSOpenPanel to always respect ⌘A while others think it should be allowed to behave differently depending upon the application. I think that's crazy.

Comment: System components simply implement the standard selectAll: responder method.   In a normal app, the default Edit NSMenu would exist, which is the class which turns an actual Command-A keystroke into a sendAction: call to NSApplication to invoke selectAll: on the first responder in the responder chain which implements it.   It's not the job of every system component to know about key bindings, and keep them consistent.  There is even a system preference where users can override default key bindings for themselves across apps.  NSMenu handles all that.

Comment: You could try creating a NSMenu with that item (or more) and assign it to the NSApp.mainMenu property, to see if that works in your situation.  Probably a good idea to have cut/copy/paste too.

Comment: Menu creation code: [Create Cocoa Document App without xib files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76464494/create-cocoa-document-app-without-xib-files/76466859#76466859)